# Laravel and Apache2 : unable to correctly use redirects

Tags: php, laravel, apache2

I have an issue with Laravel. On an intranet Apache 2.4.10 Webserver runing with Debian 8.5, named fmbsrv130, I would like to install a Laravel Project named sentinelle.

So Laravel installation is OK, I can access to it with http://fmbsrv130/sentinelle/ (I have the welcome page of Laravel). But if I try to go to http://fmbsrv130/sentinelle/1 (that does not exists), I have 404 from Apache2 that says "The requested URL /home/webadmin/sentinelle/public/index.php was not found on this server." If I try to access http://fmbsrv130/sentinelle/index.php/1 I have the 404 from Laravel : "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
1/1 NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161: ..."

rewrite_mod is correctly enabled in Apache.

Here is config file of Apache (000-default.conf in sites-available) :

```
Alias "/sentinelle" "/home/webadmin/sentinelle/public/"

    <Directory "/home/webadmin/sentinelle/public/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

For testing, if I try to modify .htaccess file from public folder of Laravel with

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.*$ htaccess_tester.php
```

(htaccess_tester.php is a file that is used to test content of .htaccessfile (see it on GitHub) and is currently into public folder), I have Apache2 404 error message `The requested URL /home/webadmin/sentinelle/public/htaccess_tester.php was not found on this server.`

Is it an issue from .htaccess file OR an issue from Apache2 config OR an issue from Laravel config OR a file access right ?

Comment: New test : if I change Apache2 config by setting `DocumentRoot /home/webadmin/sentinelle/public` everything is working fine, I can access to Laravel with http://fmbsrv130/ and http://fmbsrv130/1 displays 404 message from Laravel. Any suggest ?

Comment: did you restart apache after making changes to the conf file?

Comment: Of course I did :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so finally I found a solution by doing some modifications : first one is .htaccess file into public folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /sentinelle/

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

(Adding RewriteBase /sentinelle/)

And the second one was into default.conf Apache file :

```
Alias /sentinelle /home/webadmin/sentinelle/public/

<Directory "/home/webadmin/sentinelle/public">
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

It solved the issue described into this topic, I'll open another one because now I have issue with last "/" in address :)

Answer (score 0):

is your mod_rewrite enabled on your apache2 please confirm it should be enabled to .htaccess work and in your .htaccess file add default laravel .htaccess content

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

also if that doesn't work try to remove your index.php out of public directory and place it in root directory at `/sentinell` and modify .htaccess to `RewriteRule ^ public/index.php [L]` that should do the trick

Comment: Yes, I said mod_rewrite is enabled into Apache, I know that it work because if I change DocumentRoot as explained into my comment everything is working fine. So now I have index.php out of public folder, I've updated .htaccess and it list content of folder